# how to get json out put to html table

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to print the json out put in my php page from facebook graph url .

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?php


$jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23IIFA&access_token=TOKEN_GOES_HERE";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_encode($json);

echo $json_output;



?>
```

Out put :

```
    "data":[
      {
         "id":"1003224",
         "from":{
            "id":"1000042242",
            "name":"abc"
         },
         "message":"#abc",
         "privacy":{
            "value":""
         },
         "type":"status",
         "created_time":"2014-06-09T09:49:58+0000",
         "updated_time":"2014-06-09T09:49:58+0000"
      }
   ],
```

This page give out put as json data and i want to add the data into html layout /table 
Please advice me how to proceed

**UPDATE**

```
    $json=array();
foreach ($json_output as $json_result) {
    $json[] = array(
        'value' => $json_result["name"]

 'value' => $json_result["message"],

    );

echo $json_result['name'];
```

echo $json_result['message'];
    }

Comment: use `foreach` to echo your json into an html table. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13885786/1055987

Comment: @JFK : Kindly pls check the Update of my question i have put the code which i tried using foreach , but its not working. please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not currently navigating the JSON properly.

if your output looks like this:

```
"data":[
  {
     "id":"1003224",
     "from":{
        "id":"1000042242",
        "name":"abc"
     },
     "message":"#abc",
     "privacy":{
        "value":""
     },
     "type":"status",
     "created_time":"2014-06-09T09:49:58+0000",
     "updated_time":"2014-06-09T09:49:58+0000"
  }
],
```

JSON does not search all of its levels to find the thing you're asking for, you need to tell it exactly where to look. So, for instance, in order to get `"abc"` you need to `echo`

```
$json_result["data"][0]["from"]["name"]
```

and if you want to get `"#abc"` you need to `echo`

```
$json_result["data"][0]["message"]
```

EDIT:

try this:

```
$json=array();
foreach ($json_output["data"] as $json_result) {
    $json[] = array(
        'value' => $json_result["from"]["name"],
        'value' => $json_result["message"]
    );

    echo $json_result["from"]['name'];
}
```

Comment: :What i realy want is  display the result of this "$json_output = json_decode($json, true);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_output);
echo '</pre>';"  inside a talbe. Which means this json output is dynamic data will change daily, so i want to display them in a table format please advice

Comment: you're using the facebook graph api, right? even though the contents will always be different, if you're querying it for the same kinds of information, the JSON structure will always be the same.

Comment: Yes im using Facebook graph api . agree with u , strucr of the son will be same . im having issue with show those json data to display name and message inside html , please help , the code u mention is not works for me. pls advice

Comment: edited it to show what your foreach should look like. hopefully that works?